# What's the difference between Perl 6's DEFINITE and defined methods?

Tags: raku

Type objects are always undefined, but I've seen some tests that use `.defined` and some that use `.DEFINITE`. Is there any case where those might be different? I tend to think that any method that's all uppercase isn't for everyday work and would prefer `.defined` for this task.

```
my $class = IntStr;

put '-' x 20;  # False
put $class.DEFINITE;
put $class.defined;

put '-' x 20;   # False
$class = Nil;
put $class.DEFINITE;
put $class.defined;

put '-' x 20;   # True
$class = '';
put $class.DEFINITE;
put $class.defined;
```

In the output I'm looking for any case where the answers to the two methods would be different:

```
--------------------
False
False
--------------------
False
False
--------------------
True
True
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`.DEFINITE` should be considered a Macro (just like `.WHAT`, `.HOW` etc).   It is directly handled in the Actions and converted to a `nqp::p6definite()` op.

`.defined` is a method that lives in `Mu` and which can be overridden by your class.  It is in fact overridden for `Failure`, so that an instantiated `Failure` can act as a undefined value in e.g. an `if` statement (and "handle" the Failure).

```
my $a = Failure.new("foo");
say "bar" if $a;   # no output
say $a;            # outputs "(HANDLED) foo", but no longer throws
```

So to answer your question:

```
my $a = Failure.new("foo");
say $a.DEFINITE;  # True
say $a.defined;   # False
```